# CakePHP: URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

When I try to run my project (made with cakephp framework), I receive this error:

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server. Help me configure it I don't / can't use URL rewriting

I checked apache httpd.conf file and everything look ok. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The page is loading for more than 20 seconds, and after that display that error. But even phpmyadmin is not working.

Comment: SOLUTION: http://ryan.rawswift.com/2010/03/29/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond/

Comment: Thanks for the accept but you should post your solution as an answer and accept that instead if that was the fix - might even get the "Self-Learner" badge if people find it useful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work through the steps in the cookbook for setting up "Apache and mod_rewrite (and .htaccess)" ([1.x](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess)/[2.x](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)/[3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting)) to make sure you haven't missed anything. (If that fails, we will need more information.)

Comment: I've check that page, and are set.

Answer (score 34):

Ugh.  Before you go nuts testing out your Apache config, make sure `cake.generic.css` is available in your `app/webroot/css/` folder. This is a very misleading error message.

The state of URL rewriting is being checked indirectly by checking for access to `cake.generic.css` (which would only be found if url rewriting is working).

The red error box in the default `home.ctp` is ALWAYS shown by default.  Then the styling in `cake.generic.css` will hide it via

```
#url-rewriting-warning {
    display:none;
}
```

But that means if the `cake.generic.css` file is not found (e.g. because you deleted it to use your own CSS), the error box will *not* be hidden, ***even though URL rewriting is working perfectly fine.***

So basically, ignore the URL rewriting error on the default homepage.  Try to access one of your controller+views and see if it works.

Comment: And as soon as you change your default layout to put in your own css classes, this shows up.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for this. Spent a damn afternoon trying to figure out what was wrong when everything was fine the whole time!

Comment: The same is about `/View/Pages/home.ctp`. It should be present.

Comment: I submitted this "bug" ( https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/4116-pageshomectp-imprecise-url-rewriting-is-not-configured-error ) and Cake will no longer show this misleading error as of v2.4.2+

Answer (score 4):

I just got the same problem. The cause was the database config. I solved it by changing this in the database.php file:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',...
```

to this (rockies, please don't copy the '...' part):

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

     public $default = array(
         'driver' => 'mysql',...
```

Note: I am working on old cakephp 1.3.10

Comment: Looks like you were using a database.php from Cake 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, having all server configured. I've finally found this [discussion](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/cakephp-1-3-10-URL-rewriting-is-not-properly-configured-on-your-server-td4444962.html). My problem appeared when I created a default.ctp in app/layouts with some errors. I was calling:

```
echo $this->element('fancybox_links');
```

when that element wasn't ready and solved it by creating that element. So if you have this problem and your httpd.conf seems to be right, check for another cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issues when there was a problem with DB connectivity or extension loading (MSSQL on Windows). It is very likely not a URL rewriting issue. Since your phpmyadmin isn't working either check MySQL configuration.

Comment: You're right. I've tried a simple connection to mysql in php and it returns this error: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306)